# Get to intermediate values in middle of a functional programming chain

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm wondering if there's a concise or specific way to access values in the middle of an FP chain in JavaScript. Example:

```js
const somestuff = [true, true, false];
let filteredCount = 0;
somestuff.filter((val) => val)
  .forEach((val) => console.log(val));
```

Above, I'd like to set `filteredCount` to the length of the array returned by the `filter` function. The most straight-forward way is:

```js
const somestuff = [true, true, false];
const filteredStuff = somestuff.filter((val) => val);
let filteredCount = filteredStuff.length;
filteredStuff.forEach((val) => console.log(val));
```

This is certainly valid but it breaks our FP chain and introduces an additional holding variable. I'm wondering if there's a convention for accessing values in the middle of the chain. Something like `.once()` that runs once and implicitly returns the value passed in, but nothing like that exists.

Comment: I think you are confusing FP and OOP. There is no "chaining" in FP. Introducing multiple variables in multiple lines is simple and correct.

Comment: `filteredStuff.forEach((val,i,me) => console.log(val, me.length));` or `filteredStuff.forEach((val) => console.log(val, this), filteredStuff.length);` i use `this` a lot in "functional" js, it's a great "extra" parameter that enables stuff like `function gt(x){return x>this;}` which is then used as `[1,2,3,4,5].filter(gt, 3)`: intermediates are called `this`.

Comment: _"it breaks our FP chain and introduces an additional holding variable"_ can you explain this or give me a resource what you mean and why?

Answer (score 2):

For debugging, I often use a function called `tap` to temporarily add a side-effect *(like your `console.log`)* to a function:

```
const tap = f => x => (f(x), x);
```

This function returns whatever it is passed, but not before calling another function with the value. For example:

```js
const tap = f => x => (f(x), x);
const tapLog = tap(console.log);

const x = tapLog(10);

console.log("x is", x);
```

Your snippet basically does this:

- Filter a list
- (log the list)
- Retrieve a `length` property from an array

If you construct this function using `pipe` or `compose`, you can "inject" the `console.log` in between without interrupting the data flow:

```
const countTrues = pipe(
  filter(isTrue),
  prop("length")
);

const countTruesWithLog = pipe(
  filter(isTrue),
  tap(console.log),
  prop("length")
);
```

In a snippet:

```js
// Utils
const isTrue = x => x === true;
const prop = k => obj => obj[k];
const tap = f => x => (f(x), x);
const filter = f => xs => xs.filter(f);
const pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((res, f) => f(res), x);

// Logic:
// Filter an array using the isTrue function
// and return the length of the result
const countTrues = pipe(
  filter(isTrue),
  prop("length")
);

// Create a filter with a console.log side-effect
// and return the length of the result
const countTruesWithLog = pipe(
  filter(isTrue),
  tap(console.log),
  prop("length")
);

// App:
const somestuff = [true, true, false];

console.log("pure:");
const countA = countTrues(somestuff)
console.log(countA);

console.log("with log:")
const countB = countTruesWithLog(somestuff);
console.log(countB);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason there's no Array.prototype method like that, is that it has a side effect. This is something that is specifically avoided in functional programming. 
However if you don't care about writing 'Pure Functions', or even the functional paradigm, you could put the side effect in your callbacks, or write a function in the Array prototype.
ie.

```
Array.prototype.once = function(callback) {
    callback(this)
    return this
}
```

You also have other hacky options like in the other answer

Comment: I wonder though why you didn't put this method right on `Object.prototype`. Why should only array benefit from this? :-D

Comment: @Bergi Hah. Yeah Why not. I just mostly use arrays

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's something like that by default. What you can do is extend `Array`, but I'm not really fond of extending framework classes (clashes with other `once` implementations for example). In this case you'd end up with:

```
Array.prototype.once = function once(func) {
    func(this);
    return this;
}
```

which is called like:

```
var filteredStuff = somestuff
    .filter((val) => val)
    .once(function(array) {
        console.log(array.length);
    })
    .forEach((val) => console.log(val));
```

On the other hand, you can try to use default functions. One of these function that can access all items at once is `reduce`. Define a function `once`, that will call its first parameter once (`:)`) and you'd end up with something like:

```
function once(func) {
    return function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
        if(currentIndex === 1) {
            func(array);
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

which you'd be able to call like this:

```
var filteredStuff = somestuff
    .filter((val) => val)
    .reduce(once(function(array) {
        console.log(array.length);
    }), [0])
    .forEach((val) => console.log(val));
```

Notice the ugly `[0]` to ensure `once` calls the passed function at least once (empty array included).

Both solutions aren't too neat, but it's the best I can come up with given the criteria.